# C# Windows Forms ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I wanted to use Windows Forms for a registration form; meanwhile I decided to import ComboBox items to the array. As I press the <kbd>Save</kbd> button then I could be switching between a persons' form using <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Previous</kbd> buttons. So here is my code:

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (items != null && index < size - 1)
    {
        index++;
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox1.Items.Add(items[index]);
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = 0;
    }
}
```

Now the debugger shows me the error which is saying that the parameter 'item' can not be null.

I expected that I could allow the user to import the data to the listbox and switching between a person's information by pressing <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Previous</kbd> buttons and select the items of the combobox.

Comment: How is `'items` defined? What is its data type? When you inspect `items` while debugging, what is its value? And what is the _exact_ error?

Comment: i defined the items as an array   ' string[] items = null; '

Comment: i defined items as a string array in public partial class form1;Form

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Re *"that the parameter 'item' can not be null."*: Do you mean *'items'*?

Comment: Please put ***all*** the relevant information [in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77114685/edit), not in comments. But  *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you’re not checking if the index is out of bounds where it exceeds the index of the last item in your array. Before you add a new item to your combobox, check if the index is greater than the index of the last item in the array and reset to 0.

```
if(items != null){
   // Make sure index is within bounds
   if(index < size){
     comboBox1.Items.Clear(); 
     comboBox1.Items.Add(items[index]); 
     comboBox1.SelectedItem = 0;
     index += 1;
   }
}
```

You do not need to do `index < size -1`. That's what's causing the error in your program.

Comment: It is a bit weird to suddenly write with the typical language errors of a native US English speaker ([homophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone#English)/[homonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym#Further_examples) and [run-on sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_sentences)). Was this copied from somewhere?